# What field corresponds to "dev" (device) param in netlink?

Tags: go, netlink, iproute

I'm trying to add a new route using the [netlink](http://godoc.org/github.com/krhubert/netlink#Route) package. The equivalent I need is `ip route add $P1_NET dev $IF1 src $IP1 table $T1`. The issue is that I don't know what field corresponds to the `dev` parameter. Is there a mapping somewhere or can I use the interface index instead its name ("dev")?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the link you sent, I'd guess `IifName`. And looking [at the code](https://github.com/krhubert/netlink/blob/master/rule_test.go#L37) seems to confirm that.